how to train modle in support vectoe machine on cricket match data set
if the dataset have features like (team1, team2, venue, winner) how to plot them into a scatter and what have to find in this. I have try plot the scatter plot, but it's not working, it's not making the chart like another charts.

enter image description here
this the dataset 
